# Why doesn't awk and gsub remove only the dot?

Tags: awk

This awk command:

```
 awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {line=1} {print line "\n0" gsub(/\./, ",", $2) "0 --> 0" gsub(/\./, ",", $3) "0\n" $10 "\n"; line++}' file
```

is supposed to convert these lines:

```
Dialogue: 0,1:51:19.56,1:51:21.13,Default,,0000,0000,0000,,Hello!
```

into these:

```
1273
01:51:19.560 --> 01:51:21.130
Hello!
```

But somehow I'm not able to make `gsub` behave to replace the `.` by `,` and instead get `010` as both gsub results. Can anyone spot the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Why is your output not showing comma instead of dot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from `gsub` is not the result from the substitution. It returns the *number* of substitutions it performed.

You want to `gsub` first, then print the modified string, which is the third argument you pass to `gsub`.

```sh
 awk -F ',' 'BEGIN {line=1}
{ gsub(/\./, ",", $2);
  gsub(/\./, ",", $3);
  print line "\n0" $2 "0 --> 0" $3 "0\n" $10 "\n";
  line++}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use GNU awk's `gensub` instead of `gsub`:

```
$ awk -F ',' '
{
    print NR ORS "0" gensub(/\./, ",","g", $2) "0 --> 0" gensub(/\./, ",","g",$3) "0" ORS  $10 ORS
}' file
```

Output:

```
1
01:51:19,560 --> 01:51:21,130
Hello!
```

It's not as readable as the `gsub` solution by @tripleee but there is a place for it.

Also, I replace the `line` with builtin `NR` and `\n`s with `ORS`.